# Calls to AWS Cognito API intermittently hang using Amazon Cognito Identity for react-native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am working on a react-native application that uses the Amazon Cognito Identity for JS to manage user registration, login etc. My code works most of the time and is set up such that calls to Cognito services such as the CognitoUser.authenticateUser() method can handle both success and failure.

The issue is that, in the week I have been working on this, the service seems to simply not work for small pockets of time. I will be working on a new component, independent of the Cognito calls (so it shouldn't be affecting their execution) and suddenly, running the app simply hangs when trying to log in. In fact all server requests using the API hang during these periods, be it logging in (with valid and invalid credentials) or registering a new user, I can trace the execution of the code right up to the point that the call is made and then no output is produced. The relevant code for my login function is shown below;

```
console.log('About to authenticate user');
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {  // login successfull
        console.log("login successfull")
        CognitoUserLogin.setUpSession(result)
        callback(true, result)
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {      // login failed
        console.log(err)
        callback(false, err)
    }
})
```

As this code shows, the console logs right before calling "cognitoUser.authenticateUser" and should log immediately as soon as the function calls back with success or failure. This expected behaviour can be observed correctly most of the time but, when these calls are found to hang, the console only appears to output the first line "About to authenticate user" and nothing more, showing that the method call isn't calling back with either success or failure.

Since this code seems to perform as it should almost all the time, it seems like there isn't an issue on my end but rather with the Cognito servers however, according to their Service Health Dashboard at (https://status.aws.amazon.com/) their servers have been operating normally worldwide throughout all of these pockets of time where authentication has failed for me.

I haven't been able to find anyone mentioning this drop in service so I'm very weary that it may continue and render my app regularly unusable for seemingly random amounts of time. Has anyone else encountered this issue lately? I've only ever experienced it early in the day and the region for all of my server calls is "eu-west-1", which should have the least latency for me (living in Ireland).

To be specific, my app began hanging when trying to sign in or register a user early on Saturday 5th August 2017 (GMT) and suddenly was working again later that night. While I was working on the app with my team yesterday (8th August), the Cognito calls suddenly began hanging again for only 10-20 minutes around midday and then again (miraculously) began working. Today it stopped working for me at around 15:30 and is still not responding nearly an hour later. While it renders certain aspects of development impossible as they depend on login credentials to access Amazon services, my main concern is that a release build will have the same issues which seem to be getting more regular and painful (which would be a nightmare for a newly released app).

Any feedback would be appreciated, even people saying that they have or haven't experienced these issues when working with Cognito authentication

Comment: Also I should note that this lack of server response has been observed in the iOS simulator and a real android device

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it wasn't an issue with the AWS servers and it wasn't an issue with my login implementation. Trying an old backup of my code ran the login fine and I narrowed it down to the fact that including a separate script I was still working on prevented the callback from being called. Even though that script is only ever referenced at a later stage, the app refuses to log to the console the result of the logging in. I still don't know why exactly the new script is causing the app to fail in unrelated places but I'm getting no errors in the building nor in the console output, so whatever the issue is seems to be silently killing the execution of the function that MAY result in the buggy script from being run. Weird